# Difficulty of implementing this crawler

Tags: web-crawler

From your experience, how difficult do you think it takes to programmatically search for a term in [the Yellow Pages website](http://www.yellowpages.com/seattle/hotels?q=Hotels) and then scrape off the contact information from the results into a CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just use the [YP Search API](http://developer.yp.com/api/Listings%2520Endpoints/Search-60)?  Access is free, and it only takes a minute to set up a developer account.

Comment: This is a little off-topic, but do you remember how long it took for them to approve your developer account for API access?

Comment: @pXdty After searching through my email, it looks like it was automatically approved within minutes of registering.

Comment: thanks for that. just wanted to reply with my personal result. It seems they only reply during normal business hours, so they responded to me the following day.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl and some modules like WWW::Robot will probably be not that hard. I didn't try, but since you know Python, Scrapy might help. http://scrapy.org

Remember not to hammer the site when you crawl, because your IP can get banned.

Answer (score 0):

With the right modules and libraries its very do-able! It depends on your tools though, Perl or Python and you'll be all set. If you're trying to do this with C++ You may have a bit more pain heading your way.

If you provide more information about your situation (language frameworks constraints) I can be more specific.

Also there are legal issues to consider with scraping, I am not sure of the Yellow Pages policy on bots. Read their robots.txt before proceeding. http://www.robotstxt.org/ should give you some starting information about learning about this stuff.

The best way to be both safe and legal is to just use the API, http://developer.yp.com/

Comment: I don't know what's the best tool for the job. Also, what information would I need to provide in order to know what are the right modules and libraries? How can I find their robots.txt?

Comment: What languages do you know currently?

Comment: I would use the API as suggested by me and Bill the Lizard, safe legal and much less work, follow the link I provided above